# WCF Service Reference issue on production in console application

Tags: wcf

I have 1 c# Console Application project, which has Program.cs (that contains main method), the main method simple calls a web service method and displays the string on the console.

The service reference is added in the project by right clicking it and adding service reference it to it.

- when the console application is executed in debug mode from visual studio, it works as expected.
- when the console application is executed from a .exe found in /bin/debug, it works as expected.

so far so good.

PROBLEM:

when the project is copied over to the system (you can call it a production environment), where this .exe will actually be executed, it fails at the exact line where i create the service proxy object. the line in Program.cs is:

**ProjectName.ServiceReference.ServiceClient service = new ProjectName.ServiceReference.ServiceClient();**

I know it fails here, because i have Console.Writeline("some line"); before and after the above line. I can see the Console.Writeline that is before the proxy line, and soon after that it crashes ...

I think this is because the reference paths that are referencing the service, is there any thing i can do to change the paths, or confirm that it is the path issue as suspected ...??

any idea whats going wrong ..???

Comment: It didn't "just fail". There was an exception. What exception was thrown? If in doubt, surround your code with a try/catch block, and do Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()) on the exception.

Comment: k, just min let me do that ...

Comment: k, here we go, the exception has following message

Comment: Unrecognized element 'extendedProtectionPolicy'. (C:\Documents and Settings\DevAccount\Desktop\ProjectName\bin\Debug\ProjectName.exe.Config line 35)

Comment: where DevAccount is my development environment pc's account, and the link is also of the same system, but i have just ran this application on the client system (production system), there is no such acount or such url in that account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this link: http://blog.davidsandor.com/post/Workaround-The-configuration-for-the-servicee280a6Unrecognized-element-e28098extendedProtectionPolicye28099.aspx

> The configuration for the service reference could not be updated due
>   to the following issue: Unrecognized element
>   ‘extendedProtectionPolicy’. (App.config / Web.config)
>
> There does not seem to be a really clear reason why this is happening
>   however it seems to be related to Windows 7.  I am not sure if the
>   .NET framework that ships with Win7 has some different setting or
>   template for the WCF configuration policy files but it seems to be the
>   culprit.  Maybe the machine.config files are different on Win 7 and
>   the WCF configuration tools use the machine.config as some sort of
>   policy template.
>
> The fix is annoying (because every time you build your solution on
>   Windows 7 and then rebuild on Vista you have to redo this).
>
> Remove the line:
>
> `<extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />`
>
> from both your App/Web.config file on the client and on the WCF
>   server’s Web.config file.

Comment: @user2323308: posted content from original post